# launch xterm/urxvt with command and return to shell after exit

Tags: sh, xterm, urxvt

I want to launch a continuous running command with xterm or urxvt and after pressing Ctrl+C to exit the command I want to get a shell to enter further commands in the same window.

With non-continuous running commands I can do

```
urxvt -hold -e sh -c "echo foo; sh"
```

But with continuous running commands this does not work

```
urxvt -hold -e sh -c "tail -f /dev/null; sh"
```

After pressing Ctrl+C the command is killed but urxvt enters an unresponsive state and does not open a shell.
Same thing happens with xterm.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+C generates a `SIGINT` signal, `bash` stops the entire sequence by default. It actually lets the signal pass to the current command, and analyses the exit status of rhe command - if the command handled the `SIGINT`, `bash` continues the script, otherwise the `SIGINT` shows up in the exit status and `bash` terminates the command sequence.

There's an explanation here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479023/why-does-this-script-keep-running-after-receiving-sigint

In that case, the questioner used `sudo` to wrap the command with a signal handler. You could also look at using a subshell with the `trap` command.

(Asker reports that this works: `urxvt -e sh -c "trap sh SIGINT; tail -f /dev/null"`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this works great. You could you just add the snippet ```urxvt -e sh -c "trap sh SIGINT; tail -f /dev/null"``` to your answer? Then I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Readers can see that in your comment here, but okay I'll add that and credit you.